# Combine/filter the data in two sheets and display on a third sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to use ranges on two sheets to aggregate into a third mixed range on a third sheet. For example, on Sheet1:

```
  A   B
1 Foo 1
2 Bar 2
3 Baz 3
4 Far 4
5 Faz 5
```

On Sheet2:

```
  A
1 Bar
2 Faz
```

On Sheet3, I want:

```
  A   B
1 Bar 2
2 Faz 5
```

Basically take Sheet1 A and B, filter through Sheet2 with matching rows for A and display A and Sheet1 B on Sheet3. Is this possible? I've been messing around with `FILTER` and `QUERY` but haven't been able to get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet3 A1:

```
=ArrayFormula(Sheet2!A:A)
```

and in B1 and copied down to suit:

```
=vlookup(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I never knew about these. Thank you!